# MySQL Select any SET using IN()?

Tags: php, select, mysqli

I have a column named `post_type` `set('0', '1', '2', '3', '4')` which can be any combination of 0 to 4

Given a list of integers how can I select any row matching any of the types?
My brain has pooped and I can't even explain properly but similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM `post_content` WHERE `post_type` IN ('0','1','2');
```

So with the following set it would match all records except the last one

```
post_type
0,1,3 (matches 0 and 1)
0,3,4 (matches 0)
0,4 (matches 0)
2,3,4 (matches 2)
3,4 (not matched)
```

Many thanks

Edit: 
I understand `FIND_IN_SET` but I'm trying to avoid:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE 
FIND_IN_SET(0,post_type)>0 || 
FIND_IN_SET(1,post_type)>0 ||
FIND_IN_SET(2,post_type)>0
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set ? but that's only for single values. You're trying to find multiples, which means you'd probably be better off normalizing that set to a sub-table and then you can do a regular join.

Comment: I'm trying to match any of multiple values. Not single values.

Comment: I don't have control of the database either, just query access too. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html):

> "MySQL stores SET values numerically, with the low-order bit of the stored value corresponding to the first set member. If you retrieve a SET value in a numeric context, the value retrieved has bits set corresponding to the set members that make up the column value."

Thus, you can use [bit operations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html) to perform set arithmetic: `&` corresponds to set intersection, while `|` corresponds to union.

The only problem is that you'll need to calculate any constant bitmasks you may need in your queries yourself, based on the column definition; as far as I know, MySQL provides no convenient syntax to convert a string representation of a `SET` column value into the corresponding numeric bitmask except by assigning it to that column.

For example, in your example above, the set `0,1,2` would correspond to the bitmask 1 + 2 + 4 = 7.  Thus, you can efficiently retrieve any rows containing one of these values in the set with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM post_content WHERE post_type & (1 + 2 + 4);
```

Here's a live demo of this query: http://sqlize.com/wE4je6f28Y

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you search for SET values using the FIND_IN_SET() function or the LIKE operator:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE FIND_IN_SET('value',set_col)>0;
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE set_col LIKE '%value%';
```

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

---

So in your example, that would be:

```
SELECT * FROM post_content 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(0,post_type)>0
OR FIND_IN_SET(1,post_type)>0   
OR FIND_IN_SET(2,post_type)>0
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to bite the bullet on this one. I just thought there would be an easier way.